# Construct a layer with tensorflow to normalize a matrix/tensor

Tags: neural-network, tensorflow

Using `conv2d_transpose()` function, a matrix could be generated with size m*n (only 1 channel/filter). I just wonder how to normalize this matrix by column to make sure the sum of each column is one. It is very similar as `softmax` activation, but I don't know how to apply `softmax` activation to each column either.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just figure this out using `tf.reduce_sum()` and `tf_div()`. If you have the same question, please let me know.